# Ajax/Flash file uploads with a progress bar?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, flash

I'm looking for a simple solution that will be:

- Easy to integrate
- Allow multiple file uploads
- Show a progress bar while the file is being uploaded

Any ideas?
I've tried Swfupload and its a real pain to integrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fancy Upload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/)

No contest.

Requires [Mootools](http://mootools.net).  Easy to setup, very very powerful.  Small.

Lots of goodness.

Answer (score 1):

I've personally had good luck with a script called uploadify (It's jQuery based). It allows for multiple uploads, looks good and is very easy to integrate into any web application.

There's also another method for doing this which is server side based. You can either use the so called "secret feature" from the apc extension or a PECL extension called Upload Progress

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but aparently this is the same thing but easier
http://blogs.bigfish.tv/adam/2009/06/14/swfupload-jquery-plugin/

Comment: dont want swfuploader, it doesnt come with its own progress bar, you have to write code to integrate that