# File upload progress bar in iframe

Tags: php, jquery, html, flash

So - I am well into a project but need to adjust a file upload form to give it a progress bar. (last minute request)

I am uploading the file via an iframe so ideally want to keep the same solution if poss (No page refreshes)

My searches are drawing a blank as the only solution I have seen requires php version 5.2 and the APC module installed. I have neither (running php version 5.1.6) - can install APC if required.

I am open to anything (flash, jquery) and am really posting as a last resort to get some ideas or even gauge if its possible.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055807/ajax-flash-file-uploads-with-a-progress-bar?rq=1

Comment: appreciate the feedback but couldnt see anything I hadnt already looked at. Cant believe this is so difficult.

Comment: Does not FancyUpload have a progress bar?

Comment: yer it does but i think its running mootools - I am running jquery

Comment: The problem is mainly that jquery does not have an ajax "progress" function.  There are [some jquery plugins](https://github.com/sash/jquery-ajax-progress) out there, or you can try [this recursive technique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503658/jquery-ajax-powered-progress-bar).  Alternately, you can use Flash to get the filename and handle the transfer, then give control to PHP after that point -- progress bars are simple in Flash.